# Updating the program status to the front end in Meteor app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, backend, meteor-blaze

I have an program in the backend that takes time process. So it will be nice to tell the user the progress of it. For example to send the front-end that step 1 done, step 2 done.. likewise

I call the back-end with,

```
Meteor.call('myMethod', function(err, results){
    // get the final result here
})
```

My back-end is like,

```
Meteor.methods({
    myMethod: function(){
        // doing step 1
        // doing step 2
        // doing step 3
        // returning the final result
    }
});
```

I understand that I can  write the progress with each step to a database and reactively use it in the front-end.

But I think there is a better way to do that.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a better way than the one you suggest

Comment: @user3218741 the best way is actually using the database it will also be live and less code than using anything else ;)